# Build maven project with dependent jars built of higher jdk

Tags: java, maven, java-8

I have a maven project built with jdk7. Now, I have to add a dependency of an external jar that is built with jdk11.

When I tried to build it, it failed with

`error: cannot access <CLASS NAME>`

I want to understand if this error is because of the JDK versions mismatch or something else.

Comment: a version mismatch typically shows `major-minor version error` sort of message, do you have more logs for us to look to?

Comment: But anyway, it will not work, regardless of the current error. If you really need to build your project with such an old version of Java, you need to find similarly old dependencies for your project.